# Executing stored procedure and partitionKey

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Due to technical limitations, my app has to interact with Azure Cosmos DB using the REST API (can't use SDK).

Executing stored procedures requires supplying the `partitionKey` value,  in header `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/execute-a-stored-procedure

So the problem I'm facing is how do I get all the `partitionKey` values from a collection?

In my collection, the `partitionKey` path is `/partitionId`. So I tried to get all `partitionKey` values by running query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.partitionId 
FROM myPartition c
```

However, `SELECT DISTINCT` cannot be served through the REST API gateway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#queries-that-cannot-be-served-by-gateway

So I'm stuck on how I can execute a stored procedure when I can't retrieve the `partitionKey` values?

Comment: What kind of operation are you trying to do with a stored procedure? Is this a query? If it is a query don't use a stored procedure, do this instead, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api. If this is not a query, why don't you know what your partition key value is?